# How "file --mime-type path" works for a file wich has no extension

Tags: command-line, python, files, mime-type

To find a files mime type which we don't know we will use file command with --mime-type argument. We know it is showing results based on given file paths extension(such like text/x-python for *.py). The list about the relation between extension and mime type would be saved somewhere such as /etc/mime.type or in /usr/share/mime/glob. But what about files which doesn't have any extensions? How could we find mime type? Explain, please. Can we do the same thing using python?

Comment: What makes you think it uses the extension? Extensions are mostly decorative in Linux. Very, very few tools consider an extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extensions are mostly irrelevant in Linux systems. Unlike Windows, the vast majority of Linux tools don't rely on the extension at all. For example:

```
$ cat script.py
#!/usr/bin/python
print("Works!")
$ chmod 777 script.py 
$ ./script.py 
Works!
```

Now, with a different extension:

```
$ mv script.py script.foo
$ ./script.foo 
Works!
```

So, forget about extensions. They're very rarely relevant and `file` doesn't use them. Have a look at `man file` (please read `man file`, this is only part of the information there):

> file tests each argument in an attempt to classify it.  There are
>   three  sets of tests, performed in this order: filesystem tests, magic
>   tests,  and language tests.  The first test that succeeds causes the
>   file type to  be printed.
>
> The filesystem tests are based on examining the return from a stat(2)
>   system call.  The program checks to see if the file is empty, or if
>   it's  some sort of special file.  Any known file types appropriate to
>   the system you are running on (sockets, symbolic links, or named
>   pipes (FIFOs)  on those systems that implement them) are intuited if
>   they are defined in  the system header file .
>
> The magic tests are used to check for files with data in particular
>   fixed  formats.  The canonical example of this is a binary executable
>   (compiled  program) a.out file, whose format is defined in ,
>    and  possibly  in the standard include directory. 
>   These files have a  “magic number” stored in a particular place near
>   the beginning of the
>
> If a file does not match any of the entries in the magic file, it
>   is examined to see if it seems to be a text file.  ASCII, ISO-8859-x, non-ISO
>        8-bit extended-ASCII character sets (such as those used on Macintosh and
>        IBM PC systems), UTF-8-encoded Unicode, UTF-16-encoded Unicode, and
>        EBCDIC character sets can be distinguished by the different ranges and
>        sequences of bytes that constitute printable text in each set.  If a file
>        passes any of these tests, its character set is reported.
>
> Once file has determined the character set used in a text-type file,
>   it  will attempt to determine in what language the file is written. 
>   The lan‐  guage tests look for particular strings (cf.  )
>   that can appear  anywhere in the first few blocks of a file.  For
>   example, the keyword .br  indicates that the file is most likely a
>   troff(1) input file, just as the  keyword struct indicates a C
>   program.  These tests are less reliable than  the previous two groups,
>   so they are performed last.  The language test  routines also test for
>   some miscellany (such as tar(1) archives, JSON  files).

Comment: Can we make our own mime type reader using python without mimetype or magic like libraries.

Comment: @NewtronMalayalam probably. Although you will always need _some_ way of guessing the file type.